# how to make multi window using pyqt5

Tags: pyqt5

everybody!

Here's what I'm trying to do:
First, I created a file called basic.ui with a pushbutton.

Press the pushbutton to set the path and select the picture file in the set path to want the picture to appear in a ***new window(another window)***.

Let me tell you about the part where I am having difficulty.
The command to blow up the file is executed. Selecting the file causes an error.

I wonder what the cause is the problem.

How do I get the picture to appear in a new window(another window) after pressing the button?????

**MainActivity.python**

```
import sys
try:
    from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QT_VERSION_STR
    from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFileDialog
except ImportError:
    try:
        from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt, QT_VERSION_STR
        from PyQt4.QtGui import QImage, QApplication, QFileDialog
    except ImportError:
        raise ImportError("Requires PyQt5 or PyQt4.")
from QtImageViewer import QtImageViewer
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot

class From(QtWidgets.QDialog):    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui=uic.loadUi("basic.ui",self)
        self.ui.show()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def add_number(self):
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        viewer=QtImageViewer()
        fileName, dummy = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, "Open image file...")
        image = QImage(fileName)
        viewer.setImage(image)
        viewer.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__=='__main__':
    app=QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w=From()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Signals & Slots

Signals and slots are used for communication between objects. The signals and slots mechanism is a central feature of Qt and probably the part that differs most from the features provided by other frameworks. Signals and slots are made possible by Qt's meta-object system.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html

Try it:

```
import sys
from os import getcwd

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, pyqtSlot

class From(QtWidgets.QDialog):    
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(From, self).__init__(parent)

        self.ui=uic.loadUi("basic.ui",self)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.add_number)     # +++
        #       ^^^^^^^^^^                    vvvvvvvvvv
        #   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">   <---> "basic.ui"

        self.ui.labelImagen   = QtWidgets.QLabel()   
        self.ui.show()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def add_number(self):
        fileName, dummy = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self, "Open image file...", getcwd(),
            "Image (*.png *.jpg)",
            options=QtWidgets.QFileDialog.Options())
        if fileName:
            pix = QtGui.QPixmap(fileName)
            self.ui.labelImagen.setPixmap(pix)  
            self.ui.labelImagen.show()            


if __name__=='__main__':
    app=QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w=From()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image]